# Ubuntu 18.04 - pkexec doesn't start synaptic anymore

Tags: vpn, hdmi, synaptic, pkexec

Since a couple of days I encounter a problem with one of my app starters in the dash. When I try to start synaptic nothing happens anymore. At least most of the time. Sometimes it starts normally, but rarely. I found out that the starter launches the script '/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec', which contains the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "/usr/sbin/synaptic" "$@"
```

So I tried to use the command in a terminal like this

```
pkexec /usr/sbin/synaptic $@
```

and this

```
pkexec "/usr/sbin/synaptic" "$@"
```

Both commands start something, but no outout is given and nothing else happens.

The gnome-extension dash-to-dock is running, but I don't know if it is related to the problem. I guess not, since 'pkexec' doesn't react properly from terminal, too.

Additionally to this there is another problem, too. If the system is in the state, where 'pkexec' is not starting anything, then it is impossible for me to start a VPN-connection, too. The window pops up for a millisecond and nothing else happens. But when 'pkexec' is working properly I can establish a VPN-connection just fine. I have to say, that I tried this only via GUI, not through terminal. But I guess it wouldn't change the behavior.

Edit 1:
I would also like to know, what '$@' means in this case.

Edit 2:
When I reboot, everything works fine for some time, but after doing some stuff (vlc video watching, browsing in firefox, Telegram Desktop and RStudio) it behaves liked described.

Edit 3:
I guessed that the use of a second display via HDMI could be the cause of the problem. When I had two active screens, my secondary and external display was virtually arranged to the top left of the notebook screen. When I then started synaptics it started not on my primary screen but on my secondary. I guess it is because of lesser x,y-coordinates due to the virtual arrangement. When I later, even after reboots, worked without a secondary screen, maybe the authentification manager for synaptics, that asks for the password, started out of my screens' coordinates. There is still a problem with this theory. Usually it works fine after reboot for a while, but after some hours of work it doesn't. And this without changing any screen connection or having a second display connected.

Now I tried to verify the theory by replicating the problem and then connect my second screen. I could replicate it after working for 5 to 6 hours with firefox, VLC, RStudio and fileroller. I then connected my second screen.

1. My primary screen went black.
2. The secondary screen was black too for 20 seconds, but the mouse pointer appeared soon after connecting.
3. Both screens showed the background and last arrangement as supposed to be. But there was no authentification manager.
4. I tried to start synaptics. The auth manager started on my primary screen and after typing my password, synaptic started normally on the secondary screen. I also started VPN without any troubles.
5. I disconnected the second screen. After that it was still possible to open synaptics.
6. I opened an encrypted archive with fileroller. Afterwards synaptics still started normally.
7. I worked a little bit with RStudio. Synaptic started.
8. I rearranged the video playlist in VLC. -> the problem occured again!
9. I tried steps 1 to 4 without success of starting synaptics. The problem still occured. Additionally the menu in VLC was not responsable anymore, but even after shutting down VLC I couldn't open synaptics.
10. I wanted to shut down all programs including firefox and copy-pasted this draft text into my text editor (Kate), which started on my second screen. I dragged it to my primary screen and realised the non-responsive menu. I dragged it back to the secondary screen and the menu worked fine.

I have no idea what the problem is all about. So many different players involved here. Has anyone an idea what is going on?

Comment: You don't see any messages in the terminal after executing "pkexec synaptic"? What other programs do you try to start with pkexec? Will work only if there is a policy file.

Comment: There are no messages in the terminal. Just a new line, where I see the keys and control symbols I hit on the keyboard. Actually I just tried to start pkexec without anything and different kinds of synaptic-commands. I had no idea how it works or what other program it is used for.